# Laravel 5.7 Multiple foreign key referencing to same table primary key

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I have a table `Task` where it has `creatorID` and `assignedTo`. Both of them are foreign keys to my `User` table's primary key `u_id`. I'm trying to display the names of the `creatorID` and `assignedTo` but it is not working, it gave an error `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`. Anyone able to spot whats wrong with my code? I'm opened to any suggestions or modifications to my models/tables thank you.

**Task Table(Migration)**

```
Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('t_id');
    $table->string('t_name');
    $table->date('start_date');
    $table->date('end_date');
    $table->string('status');
    $table->unsignedInteger('creatorID');
    $table->unsignedInteger('assignedTo')->nullable();
    $table->unsignedInteger('p_id');
    $table->foreign('creatorID')->references('u_id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('assignedTo')->references('u_id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('p_id')->references('p_id')->on('projects');
    $table->string('priority');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**User Table(Migration)**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('u_id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->string('status');
    $table->string('picture');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Task Model**

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','u_id');
}

public function assignedTo(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','assignedTo');
}
```

**User Model**

```
public function tasks(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Task','u_id');
}

public function assignedTo(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Task','assignedTo');
}
```

**Query**

```
$ActiveTasks = Task::where('p_id',$projectID)->where('status','active')->get();
```

**Blade File**

```
@foreach($ActiveTasks as $task)
    <p>{{$task->assignedTo->name}}</p>   <<< NOT WORKING
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update the `assignedTo` relationship in your `Task` model so that it knows to reference `u_id` instead of `id`:

```php
public function assignedTo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class, 'assignedTo', 'u_id');
}
```

According to the docs:

> If your parent model does not use id as its primary key, or you wish
>   to join the child model to a different column, you may pass a third
>   argument to the belongsTo method specifying your parent table's custom
>   key
>
> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

You should also check the tasks table to see if the `assignedTo` column is null for any of the saved records. Since you have the `nullable` attribute set, any records that had a null value in `assignedTo` would also produce the `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object` error when the relationship was accessed. If that's the case, you can define the relationship using the `withDefault()` method:

> The `belongsTo` relationship allows you to define a default model that
>   will be returned if the given relationship is null. This pattern is
>   often referred to as the Null Object pattern and can help remove
>   conditional checks in your code
>
> https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Comment: it still didnt work after i added the third argument in the `assignedTo` function. I'm still getting the same error `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object` any ideas why?

Comment: Are you sure the related model exists in your database?